# How do I find all Google groups I am member of via api?

Tags: google-apps

I have a Google Apps account (now, G Suite). I want to find out all groups I am member of via api call. I know that this can be done from UI. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46711/where-can-i-see-the-groups-i-am-a-member-of-in-my-enterprise-account  . But I need to do this from an api call. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at the following github project which uses Python to call google-groups-APIs: https://github.com/alfasin/Google-Admin-Directory-API I think that [this function](https://github.com/alfasin/Google-Admin-Directory-API/blob/master/google_groups_rest.py#L14) should do the trick

Comment: I think I found it https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups

Comment: Yes that's the API that the project uses.

Answer (score 1):

Google Admin SDK has an api for this. This is the api to use.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups